# how to convert a pandas column containing list into dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe. 
One of its columns contains a list of 60 elements, constant across its rows.

How do I convert each of these lists into a row of a new dataframe?

Just to be clearer: say A is the original dataframe with n rows. One of its columns contains a list of 60 elements.

I need to create a new dataframe nx60.

My tentative:

```
def expand(x):
return(pd.DataFrame(np.array(x)).reshape(-1,len(x)))
df["col"].apply(lambda x: expand(x))]
```

it gives funny results....

The weird thing is that if i call the function "expand" on a single raw, it does exactly what I expect from it

```
expand(df["col"][0])
```

[image]

To ChootsMagoots: Thjis is the result when i try to apply your suggestion. It does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`new_df = pd.DataFrame(df["col"].tolist())`

This is a little frankensteinish, but you could also try:

`import numpy as np
np.savetxt('outfile.csv', np.array(df['col'].tolist()), delimiter=',')
new_df = pd.read_csv('outfile.csv')`

Comment: Nope. It does not work either... I will try to post the screenshot

Comment: Can you check and see if df['col'].tolist() is a list of lists? If so, my edit should work

Comment: Your first suggestion works great! It was my fault: since I imported the dataframe from a file, what I believed it was a list was actually a string-fied version of list. By appling df['liwc']=df["liwc"].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)) first and your suggested command afterwards, I have obtained what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sample data

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col'] = np.arange(4*5).reshape(4,5).tolist()
df
```

Output:

```py
    col
0   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1   [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2   [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
3   [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

now exctract `DataFrame` from `col`

```py
df.col.apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```py
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2   10  11  12  13  14
3   15  16  17  18  19
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as well:

```
newCol = pd.Series(yourList)
df['colD'] = newCol.values
```

The above code:
1. Creates a pandas series.
2. Maps the series value to columns in original dataframe.